# Burp proxy error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:127.0.0

Tags: firefox, burp

I've installed burp, and set up a listener, according to the instructions here:
http://portswigger.net/burp/help/suite_gettingstarted.html

I'm now trying to configure firefox to use the burp listener as a proxy. I've followed the instructions on that page. The only difference between the documentation and how I've set things up is that I've used a slightly different path to get to the proxy settings. (edit->preferences->advanced->network)

I've set the http proxy to 127.0.0.1:8080, in accordance with the docs.

When I send a request, the first request gets to the burp listener. But when I let it through, I see this in the firefox pane

```
Burp proxy error: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:127.0.0.
```

I've looked very closely at my config. I'm absolutely certain that I haven't dropped the '1'.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score -3):

you should put a tick before "Use SOCKS proxy",see below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Upr.png)

and then,add "1" behind "127.0.0." and add "0" behind "108"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPVeH.png)

last,put a tick before "Use SOCKS proxy" again,and it will be okay
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46Of.png)